# A function $\phi(x) = x^3$ from $\mathbb{R}$ under addition to itself is not an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning, group-isomorphism

I'm working my way through Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra (9th edition). In chapter six which is about isomorphisms there is the following example on page 123

**Example 3:** The mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ under addition to itself given by $\phi(x) = x^3$ is not an isomorphism. Although $\phi$ is one-to-one and onto it is not operation preserving, since it is not true that $(x + y)^3 = x^3 + y^3$ for all $x, y$.

My problem is with the operation preserving portion. Here is my solution:

**Solution:** Write $G = (\mathbb{R}, +)$ and $\bar{G} = (\mathbb{R}, +)$. Let $\phi : G \to \bar{G}$ such that $x \mapsto x^3$. To check whether $\phi$ is operation preserving, we must determine whether $\phi(x + y) = \phi(x) + \phi(y)$ holds for all $x, y \in G$. We get

\begin{aligned}
\phi(x + y) &= (x + y)^3 \\
&= 3(x + y) & \mbox{(additive)} \\
&= (x + y) + (x + y) + (x + y) \\
&= 3x + 3y & \mbox{(addition is commutative)} \\
&= x^3 + y^3 & \mbox{(additive)} \\
&= \phi(x) + \phi(y)
\end{aligned}

Which shows that $\phi(x)$ is an isomorphism contrary to Gallian. This is for self-study so I would appreciate a hint.

Comment: By $\phi(x) = x^3$, the author really does mean multiplication. The step $(x+y)^3 = 3(x+y)$ is where things go wrong.

Comment: The third power of a number is not the same as $3$ times the number (unless that number is zero or $\pm\sqrt3$:)

Comment: I see. I thought that "under addition" meant I was to interpret all powers as multiplication. Thank you.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Please write that as an answer so we can get this Q out of the 'unanswered' queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gallian's intent, as pointed out by @AymanHourieh in the first comment, is that $x\mapsto x^3$ is understood to be multiplicative, not additive.

Then $$\begin{align}\phi(x+y)&=(x+y)^3 \\ &=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3 \\ &\neq x^3+y^3 \tag{1} \\ &=\phi(x)+\phi(y),\end{align}$$ where $(1)$ holds when, say, $x=y=42$.

Hence $\phi$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: This is a minor complaint, but in some groups, $3x^2y$ and  $3xy^2$ are identically equal to $0$ (although not in the group under question). I think it's better to exhibit specific $x$ and $y$ where $(x+y)^3$ is not equal to $x^3 + y^3$, especially at the OP's level, where they are still learning how familiar notation can have un-expected meanings in abstract algebra.

Comment: Is that any better, @JonathanZ?